# How to avoid SpringJUnit4ClassRunner initializing beans before them being mocked with JMockit?

Tags: java, spring, junit4, jmockit

I have a JUnit test class like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration( locations = { "beanDefinitions.xml"})
public class MyTest {

    @Mocked private SomeDependency usedInSpringContext;

    @Test public void letsTest() {
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem is, Spring runner loads its beans before JMockit gets a chance to mock them. How to avoid it? This is JMockit 1.0 and Spring 3.07. I'd rather had my beanDefinitions.xml unchanged.

The code under test is legacy. It contains lots of hardcoded spring dependencies I cannot get rid of easily. Thus the first step - mocking.

Comment: There are ways to lazy load beans but I dont think thats the issue here

Comment: It sounds like you want contradictory things. You are telling Spring to initialise your beans, but then you are saying you don't want Spring to initialise them. I suggest writing a real unit test and not using any Spring.

Comment: There is no "error". I do not get my stuff properly mocked, like db access, etc. Good point with avoiding spring, but this is legacy app we are starting to test. Extracting classes for unit testing without spring would take ages. That's why we are starting with heavy mocking.

Comment: Have you considered letting Spring inject your beans and then setting them on your objects using setters or reflection in your unit test code?

Comment: Do you want the dependency classes injected by Spring to be mocked *before* they are instantiated, or is it ok if they are mocked *after* injection? If the latter, then you can add `@Capturing` to the mock field to have JMockit automatically mock the implementation class.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom FactoryBean.

It is explained in this [blog](http://www.jayway.com/2011/11/30/spring-integration-tests-part-i-creating-mock-objects/). And [here](https://gist.github.com/matsev/1397610#file_easy_mock_factory_bean.java) is the example code.

It uses either easymock or Mockito. But I am sure you can easily port that to JMockit.

EDIT: I overlooked that you don't want your beanDefinitions.xml to be modified. But my suggestion includes that modification.

Answer (score 0):

One of the great things about Spring, and dependency injection in general, is that your classes don't get cluttered up with code to satisfy thier dependencies. They just sit and wait for someone else to fill in collaborating objects. So it is supposed to be trivial to plug in mock objects.

```
// no Spring runner or context configuration
public class FooTest {
    Foo foo;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        foo = new Foo();
        foo.setDependency(mock(dependency)); // details depend on mocking framework
    }
}
```

With this approach you don't autowire or otherwise inject the object you're testing, at least not if you intend to reconfigure it by pointing it at mock collaborators. If the code under test has lots of dependencies, you can wind up with a ton of setup code, but that's normal.

Admittedly, some things (like databases) are hard to mock, so you need a different testing approach to verify that your SQL queries (for example) do what you meant. This starts with a separate bean definitions file containing something like:

```
<jdbc:embeded-database id="datasource"/>
```

See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html for more information.

The tricky part is that if you haven't been writing Junit tests all along, your may have gotten into a situation where every bean seems to depend on every other bean. So the "unit" you're trying to test isn't one class, but an bunch of interrelated classes. In that case I suggest breaking the bean definitions file into smaller parts, then write unit tests for each part.

With that approach you can let Spring wire up the code under test, because the Spring configuration is part of the unit. The unit test code still mocks and plugs in the dependencies external to that unit.

If you insist on using your real beanDefinitions.xml file in its entirety, you're writing integration tests, not unit tests.

Comment: As I stated in my question - this is legacy code. I do not have time nor money to refactor it.

Comment: I didn't suggest that you refactor it. I'm trying to answer the question you asked about how to mock dependencies so you can test it.